# Can organic acids be concentrated and used like concentrated sulfuric acid and similar mineral acids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, concentration

Is it possible to make organic acids concentrated like inorganic acids like concentrated sulfuric acid and similar mineral acids?

Comment: mostly because they are usually solid. Some that are not, are used, like acetic acid.

Comment: @permeakra depending on your climate zone, also acetic acid is solid. ;-)

Comment: ".. used like inorganic acids ..."  For what? There are not so many cases where I would say "throw in any inorganic acid, no matter which".

Answer (score 6):

They can. Vinegar is typically 4-18% acetic acid by mass, but of course concentrated acetic acid also exists with a concentration >90% by mass. It is corrosive and flammable, but it surely exists.

Comment: Some can and some can't maybe? Not all inorganic acids can be concentrated to >90%.

Comment: @fp, well some inorganic acids, say, carbonic acid, also can not be concentrated. But *in general* one could concentrate both inorganic and organic acids as well as any other substances.

Comment: Glacial acetic acid is 100% acetic acid. There are many organic acid available at 100%: phthalic acid, ascorbic acid, citric acid, etc...

Comment: There are a number of very important inorganic acids which are either gaseous (all hydrogen halides) or unstable (carbonic acid, nitrous acid). No organic acid of the same description springs to mind.